# SpecFlow AfterTestRun not triggering

Tags: nunit, automated-tests, bdd, specflow, atdd

In SpecFlow the AfterTestRun calls are not triggering. We are correctly Binding the class at the top. After a google we found that this issue occured with an older version of NUnit and there was a bug fix.

However we are now using the latest version of NUnit 2.6.4 and the latest versions of SpecFlow 1.9.0 and SpecFlow NUnit 1.1.1

Comment: Can you please post the code for your "AfterTestRun"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue to be older versions of NUnit core running, updated these now and it all triggers.